# Can someone explain this code in javascript where a function has formal parameter as an object

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

In a Vue component's methods I read this code where a function is defined this way

```
methods : {
   onEditorChange({ editor, html, text }) {
        console.log('editor change!', editor, html, text)
        this.content = html
   }
}
```

I checked the code and it is working. Can we declare formal parameters to a function like that ?
You can find the code snippet in
https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

Comment: new javascript ES2016+

Comment: This is ES6 syntax. Look up object destructing.

Comment: Which part exactly are you unclear on, `{ editor, html, text }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as `Destructuring`.

From:
http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#parameter-handling

In ECMAScript 5, you’d implement selectEntries() as follows:

```
function selectEntries(options) {
    options = options || {};
    var start = options.start || 0;
    var end = options.end || getDbLength();
    var step = options.step || 1;
    ···
}
```

In ECMAScript 6, you can use destructuring, which looks like this:

```
function selectEntries({ start=0, end=-1, step=1 }) {
    ···
};
```

Comment: Understood the concept you were telling [here](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/)

Comment: @Bhargav Yeah that page looks like a good intro into the concept. Thanks for sharing :)